# Discrepancy in SAL annotation between the Windows SDK and MSDN documentation

Tags: winapi

Can somebody explain this SAL annotation discrepancy in UnmapDebugInformation?

In the MSDN library [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the DebugInfo parameter is annotated as being passed **in**:

```
BOOL WINAPI UnmapDebugInformation(
    _In_ PIMAGE_DEBUG_INFORMATION DebugInfo
);
```

In DbgHelp.h, however, the parameter is annotated as being passed **out**:

```
BOOL IMAGEAPI UnmapDebugInformation(
    _Out_writes_(_Inexpressible_(unknown)) PIMAGE_DEBUG_INFORMATION DebugInfo
);
```

Why would this parameter be annotated as `_Out_` in the SDK?

(I understand that this a deprecated function; I'm interested in understanding the SAL annotation used in the SDK.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAL annotations evolve separately from MSDN documentation and SDK updates.  The MSDN article tends to be stale, this may well have once been annotated as `_In_` in the SDK as well.  Oldest one I got is SDK v6.0, it uses `__out_xcount(unknown)`.

I supposed the passed structure may well be updated by the function, considering it contains a list so what you see is just a better version. It only really matters to code analyzers.